# RedirectMatch matching hostname

Tags: linux, apache-httpd

I'm using apache 2.4

I would like to redirect any HTTP traffic to HTTPS matching any canonical domain of the apex domain. I know it's possible to do it via RewriteRules but I would like to use RedirectMatch instead, where it takes the domain name from the HTTP header.

```
ServerName exampledomain.com
ServerAlias *.exampledomain.com
<If "%{SERVER_PROTOCOL} != 'HTTPS'">
RedirectMatch (.*) "https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1"
</If>
```

So when you ask for `http://anynameyoucanimagine.exampledomain.com` it redirects you to `https://anynameyoucanimagine.exampledomain.com`.

Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

the following lines should be simply enough

```
ServerName anynameyoucanimagine.exampledomain.com
RedirectMatch /(.*) https://anynameyoucanimagine.exampledomain.com/$1
```

Comment: Yeah, but I can't have it hard written, there are hundreds of subdomain names which I need to match.

Comment: if %{HTTP_HOST} variable does not work, you may need to use mod_rewrite as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059463/redirect-all-subdomains-from-http-to-https#23059640

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asking if anyone has any idea solving it via RedirectMatch. Also mod_rewrite is slower then redirect.

Comment: Since I think there is not a possible way to do it one line using RedirectMatch, and you do not want to use mod_rewrite because its less performant, I think you have to repeat the above lines or similar, for all the hundreds VHosts. Or better, I think you will have to give up and use mod_rewrite at the end